# When I run a program with Java Web Start, it doesn't show me the errors

Tags: java, netbeans, java-web-start

I configured Netbeans to run a program with Java Web Start.
The program compiles fine, but then when it runs, it tries to load a file (a sound clip) that was not in the place it expected to find it in. Here Java Web Start just pauses. It doesn't show me any errors, either in the output tab of Netbeans, or in the Java Console (which is what it shows me when I open the html page and run it as an applet).

Any idea how I can configure things so that errors are displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you deal with Java WebStart it is really nice to enable the Java Console (see Control Panel -> Java under Windows), and turn on full debug log.

Am I right in assuming you are looking for a stack trace?

Comment: Thats right.
I set the console to always show, and then set the debugging options to enable tracing, and show lifecycle exceptions.

Comment: Yeah, but I then turned off the Java console. Because once tracing was enabled, the errors were showed up in both a pop up and in the console

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen: might you know if is it possible to obtain java console in any way if i build my app from IDE? (netbeans in this particular case)

Comment: @Julia, this is a global JVM setting that the user must enable.  This is not the usual java.exe/javaw.exe difference.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen, hmmm yes i know, and when i run my app as JNLP i see the java console. But I wonder if there is chance to do see it as well when i run my app from netbeans, but it doesnt seem to..anyways thanx!